# Vaadin Multiple GridLayout

Tags: loops, components, vaadin, grid-layout

Please help me out,
I am using Vaadin's GridLayout inside a for loop like

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < SubjectLength; i++) 
                    {
                    GridLayout tableHeader= new GridLayout(3,1);
                    tableHeader.addComponent(TopicTitle);
                    tableHeader.addComponent(MinHr);
                    tableHeader.addComponent(Streams);
                    tableHeader.setWidth("300px");
                    tableHeader.addStyleName(TABLEHEADER_STYLE);
                    }
```

The problem is that multiple addition of GridLayout ends in adding gridLayout at the last value of loop.But if i try to do System.out.println("print")
It result in printing correct number of print value.
What should i do in order to add multiple GridLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the same component more than once in a layout. You'll have to create new instances of TopicTitle, MinHr and Streams.